# Extracting the full content of an html tag using Xpath

Tags: html, xpath

I have a set of html pages (over which I don't have any control) and need to extract the complete contents of an li tag as a single block of text including whitespace and all markup other than the li tag pair. I'm using the HTML Xpath parser 1.0 (and don't have a choice about that.)

Input html looks like

```html
<ul class="gs-source-list">
<li id="s1" class="gs-source-item">
[S1] First text here
<br/>
<br/>
Label:
<br/>
<br/>
<span style="display:inline-block; margin-left:35px;">
More text
<br/>
More text
<br/>
</span>
<br/>
<br/>
Note: 
<br/>
<br/>
<span style="display:inline-block; margin-left:35px;">GRO reference is Note text</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

`.//*[@class='gs-source-item']` gets me the text I want, but with the opening and closing li tags.

`.//*[@class='gs-source-item']//text()` get me the text as separate elements (rather than as a single element) but not the inner tags.

`string(.//*[@class='gs-source-item']//text())` gets me the first line of text only.

`string-join(.//*[@class='gs-source-item']//text(),"")` doesn't seem to be acceptable syntax for the parser I'm using and anyway I think it would still strip out the inner tags.

`.//*[@class='gs-source-item']//node()` gets me all the text and tags but not as a single block.

I've run out of ideas to try... I've looked at related questions but not found anything to help (apart from the ideas I've listed above).

Comment: Try `//*[@class='gs-source-item']/*` - this returns a collection of the elements within the list.

Comment: @tomredfern That returns the contents of the inner tags but not the top level text.

Comment: Sorry I'll read your question properly next time.

Answer (score 0):

There are no XPath functions to return HTML tags as text.  You don't mention if you are accessing via a programming language, but I would perform this using code instead.

Read in the HTML source and parse it manually.

Comment: That isn't an option unfortunately. However,  //node() does seem to return the tags as well as the text; I just can't work out how to concatenate the results.

Comment: Possibly by surrounding it with [string-join()](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp#string)?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work (I'm stuck with Xpath 1.0 and I think string-join is 2.0?  concat doesn't work either -- because the string-value of a node-set is the string-value of the first node.